# js regex - match either space with specific character

Tags: javascript, regex

In following string i want to match one that has space(s) before or after hyphen, but it's ok if not any space:

a) `54 -4 Broadway`  - Match
b) `54 - 4 Broadway` - Match
c) `54-  4 Broadway` - Match
d) `54-4 Broadway`   - should NO match

```
\s*-\s*
```

<- matches also last example but is not needed.

caputuring groups? matches last case too ->

```
(\s*-\s*)|(^\s-^\s)
```

thanks

Comment: Use plus in combination with pipe: `\s+-\s*|\s*-\s+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is regex that works in this case (someone posted it but deleted later...):

```
str.match(/\s+-\s*|-\s+/)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
/\d+(?!-\d)\s*?-\s*?\d+\s*?Broadway/g
```

The regex matches `one or more digits`, followed by a `negative lookahead` for a `hyphen` and a `digit`.

Then it matches zero or more `White Spaces`, a `hyphen` and zero or more `White Spaces`, followed by one or more `digits` and zero or more `White Spaces`, ending with the string `'Broadway'`.

**Edit** according to comment:

```
/\w+(?!-\w)\s*?-\s*?\w+.*/g
```

Now it will match `Word` characters (which includes numbers) instead of digits and match the rest of the line no matter what text it is.

Still, it doesn't match: 54-4 Broadway.

Comment: it's just example, it can be also 12B - 12C or A - B Central Ave. -- i made example too specific..

Comment: actually, i didn't phrase the question correctly. I only need to remove either space (if any) before or after hyphen. your answer works correctly (it matches whole line if space-space)  but not for my case. but good to know about lookahead. thanks